# All OpenGL ES 2 apps crash in Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, emulation

The Hyper-V based emulator runs everything else fine, but when I run my OpenGL ES 2.0 based apps **(which run fine on my Samsung Galaxy S3 device)** I see the 'Unfortunately, appName has stopped'

I see the following debug output in Android Studio

```
08-17 04:03:04.038    1024-1037/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 75
Process: mrmagoo.com.openglestest, PID: 1024

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

The emulator is now supposed to support OpenGL ES 2.0
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/02/23/the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-vs2015-ctp6.aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: Any updates? Because I want to use the emulator to run other games.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

Before calling

```
setRenderer(Renderer);
```

A dev from Microsoft answered me on reddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3hbd00/visual_studio_emulator_for_android_not_running/cu76v4o

Comment: Some devices will ignore the alpha channel being set to 0 bits, but it is a best practice to set it.